# Setting up foreign keys in EF Code First to existing SQL Server database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a comment class that contains a user object for the comment author / last person to modify the comment.

```
public class Comment 
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int SignOffId { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public int LastModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedOnDate { get; set; }
    public virtual User LastModifiedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to setup the relationship in the `CommentMap` class but I can't figure out how to do it without putting a virtual `Comment` property in the `User` class. But I don't want this because it doesn't make sense from the business logic for the `User` class to have a `Comment` object.

`LastModifiedByUserId` is the foreign key in the `Comments` table pointing to the `User` table.

Here's the `CommentMap` ctor.

```
    public CommentMap() {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.CommentId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.CommentText)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsMaxLength();

        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedByUserId)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedOnDate)
            .IsRequired();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Comments");
        this.Property(t => t.CommentId).HasColumnName("CommentId");
        this.Property(t => t.SignOffId).HasColumnName("SignOffId");
        this.Property(t => t.CommentText).HasColumnName("CommentText");
        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedByUserId).HasColumnName("LastModifiedByUserId");
        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedOnDate).HasColumnName("LastModifiedOnDate");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(c => c.LastModifiedByUser)
            .WithRequiredDependent(u => u.UserId) //This doesn't work
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.LastModifiedByUserId);
    }
```

It wants an entity in the `WithRequiredDependent` line, not an integer. Is this completely the wrong way to setup this relationship? When I pull a comment from the db I want it to also grab the User object for the person who last modified the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that a user can only modify one comment. Because that's what your model expresses. The combination `HasRequired - WithRequiredDependent` expresses a 1:1 relationship. It should be 1:n, as follows:

```
this.HasRequired(c => c.LastModifiedByUser)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.LastModifiedByUserId);
```

Comment: You can leave the parameter list blank?